# sequelize distinct ,count and grouping

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I have a database of uploaded files , each file can have one of 4 stages; recieved, converting, done and failed. need to bring a count of each stage for each. The date is stored in the "ReceivedAt" column in ms.
this is my code. it works, but it takes a long time to get all the information out.

```
const dates = await Job.aggregate("recievedAt", "DISTINCT", { plain: false });
  const dates_sorted = dates.sort((a, b) => a - b);

  const rev_date = dates_sorted.reverse();
  let day;

  const summery_by_date = [];
  try {
    await Promise.all(
      rev_date.map(async (date) => {
        const string_d = new Date(Number(date.DISTINCT)).toDateString();
        if (!(day === string_d)) {
          day = string_d;

      const d_num = new Date(Number(date.DISTINCT));
      const date_midnight = d_num.toISOString().split("T")[0];
      const beaging_date = Number(new Date(date_midnight).getTime());
      const end_date = Number(beaging_date + 86400000);

      const total = await Job.count({
        where: {
          recievedAt: {
            [Op.between]: [beaging_date, end_date],
          },
        },
      });
      const failed = await Job.count({
        where: {
          [Op.and]: [
            {
              recievedAt: {
                [Op.between]: [beaging_date, end_date],
              },
            },
            { stage: "failed" },
          ],
        },
      });
      const converting = await Job.count({
        where: {
          [Op.and]: [
            {
              recievedAt: {
                [Op.between]: [beaging_date, end_date],
              },
            },
            { stage: "converting" },
          ],
        },
      });
      const recieved = await Job.count({
        where: {
          [Op.and]: [
            {
              recievedAt: {
                [Op.between]: [beaging_date, end_date],
              },
            },
            { stage: "recieved" },
          ],
        },
      });
      const done = await Job.count({
        where: {
          [Op.and]: [
            {
              recievedAt: {
                [Op.between]: [beaging_date, end_date],
              },
            },
            { stage: "done" },
          ],
        },
      });

      summery_by_date.push({
        date: beaging_date,
        total: total,
        failed: failed,
        converting: converting,
        recieved: recieved,
        done: done,
      });`
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You mention grouping in title, why not trying the group by?